# Get PR files even before checkout is performed in Github action

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to get the changes done in a PR without using the checkout action?

Why I need this:
The repo consists of multiple (around 10) C# solutions placed in different folders and we build them in parallel using a matrix. A PR check is performed whenever a PR is raised. Since they run in parallel, each runner downloads (checkout) the source and then builds the C# solution. It takes around 2 minutes to download and then download the required dotnet SDK and etc.

We can only run the C# solutions if a change is performed on a specific folder and we build only that C# solution instead of building all the C# solutions.

There are actions (like actions/changed-files etc) to check whether changes were made to a specific path, but I need to checkout the whole repo before using those actions. Not checking out saves around 18-20 mins of time.

Also we can move the solutions to its own repo, but cant do it at the moment.

Comment: So, you don't want to checkout when the PR check is performed? The build job is different from this check job?

Comment: Thats right, dev build is a separate one, this is PR build check. Seems like there is an action already available https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter#conditional-execution "Use change detection to configure matrix job". Just exploring it now